# Comment traduire « bigot » en français?

Tags: traduction, anglais, expressions-idiomatiques

En anglais il existe le mot « bigot » (arrivant de l'exclamation « *by God* » — par Dieu) pour décrire une personne qui est intolérante, peut-être aux vues étroites, et qui n'hesite pas à exprimer ses opinions.  La langue française a-t-elle un mot ou une phrase courante qui pourrait posséder la même signification ?

[Google Translate](http://translate.google.com/) et [PROMT](http://www.online-translator.com/Default.aspx/Text) traduisent ce mot par « *fanatic* » — fanatique —, ce qui me suggère que le mot français *bigot* n'est pas un mot courant, et ne sera pas compris par beaucoup de locuteurs français.  Mais je suis sûr que *fanatique* n'a pas le même sens.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Le mot français est courant, voir par exemple :

> Si j'étais Dieu en les voyant prier
>   Je crois que je perdrais la foi
>   Par les bigotes
>       *(Jacques Brel)*

mais n'a pas eu l'extension de sens de l'anglais et reste confiné aux personnes à la pratique religieuse en même temps excessive, ritualiste et simpliste mais pas nécessairement intolérante. *Fanatique*, *extrémiste*, *intégriste*, *borné*, *buté* sont plus proches de l'usage actuel anglais, mais aucun ne me semble avoir le sens exact.

Answer (score 10):

La version française du mot "bigot" tel que tu le décris ci-dessus est a priori correcte, même si le sens français est un peu moins fort (il s'agit plus d'une personne à la pratique religieuse exagérée, que d'une personne vraiment intolérante). Pour donner une nuance d'intolérance religieuse ("fundamentalist"), on utilisera plutôt "intégriste".

En revanche, le sens *moderne* de "bigot" en anglais a nettement divergé de cette définition originale, pour couvrir pratiquement toute forme d'intolérance (y compris non-religieuse): on le retrouve souvent comme un synonyme de "raciste" ou "homophobe", par exemple. Ce sens plus étendu n'est absolument pas couvert par la version française (qui reste étroitement liée à la religion).

Comment: Et souvent utilisé en *ad hominem* comme synonyme de « quelqu'un qui ne pense pas comme moi »...

Answer (score 8):

*Bigot* can be translated as *[bigot](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/bigot)*, while *zealot* can be translated as *[zélote](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/z%C3%A9lote)*. Also note that the English *bigot* [comes from the French *bigot*](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=bigot) (12th century), but the etymology of it coming from “bi Got” / “by God” is considered as doubtful.

Comment: Curious... most translators don't translate it as 'bigot', which you'd think would be the path of least resistance!  How commonly would it be understood in the francophone world?

Comment: @Jez if you already have data about its uses and translations, please add that to your question. In fact, it would make it much more interesting if it's a question between the differences in meaning between the French and English *bigot*, than a simple one-short translation!

Comment: Oh, you meant “computer translators”? Well, I wouldn't be worried then :)

Comment: Yeah, but judging by some other comments here, it seems they were right not to translate it to *bigot* - that word has much more of a religious sense in French.

Answer (score 6):

- Dans le langage courant, en France, on utilise souvent l'expression *intégriste*. A l'origine, ce qualificatif ne s'appliquait qu'à des questions religieuses, mais ce n'est plus le cas.

Par exemple, on pourrait tout à fait entendre:

> -Que penses-tu de *tel musicien* ?
>   -Il est doué mais c'est un intégriste ! Pour lui, tout ce qui n'est pas jazz n'est pas musique.

Ou encore:

> *Untel*  est un intégriste de la langue française. Ne t'avise pas d'employer un anglicisme en sa présence !

- Certains utilisent le terme *ayatollah*. Je l'entends assez souvent mais ne le recommande pas du fait de sa trop grande proximité avec la religion.

Comment: Franchement, je ne crois pas qu'on utilisera le mot "bigot" en anglais pour n'importe lequel de vos exemples.

Comment: "décrire une personne qui est intolérant, peut-être aux vues étroites, et peut-être vocale à propos ses opinions.", c'est bien ça, non ?

Comment: Ca vaurdait peut-être la peine de poser la question sur EL&U

Comment: Oui, si la question est relative à l'usage anglais, c'est le mieux. Je me suis borné aux indications données et à la langue française ici.

Comment: Ma résumé bref n'a pas décrit le sens exactement, mais ça ne rend pas cette question invalide pour ce site.  C'est encore une question de traduction; ma résumé est seulement pour plus de clarté.

Comment: @Jez ta question est tout à fait valide pour ce site. Et si en plus de cette dernière se pose une interrogation connexe et relative à l'usage anglais de *bigot*, c'est sur EL&U qu'il faut le voir. C'est ce dernier point qui est discuté ci-dessus.

Comment: integriste = fundamentalist

Answer (score 5):

"**Bigot**" désigne en anglais une personne qui a une opinion tranchée, définitive, sur un sujet, quel qu'il soit (faut-il verser le lait d'abord ou le thé ; question analogue pour le sucre, il y a donc quatre opinions différentes, sans compter ceux qui ne mettent pas de lait, ou pas de sucre, ou ni l'un ni l'autre).

**Il s'agit donc d'un esprit :**

**a) qui a une opinion ;**

**b) et ne veut ou ne peut pas comprendre, et encore moins admettre une autre.**

L'équivalent exact me semble "**sectaire**", étant donné que le mot "secte" n'est plus exclusivement réservé aux matières religieuses ni philosophiques.

Les propositions des réponses antérieures ne me semblent pas exactes :

1- "*borné*", "*buté*" signifient incapable de comprendre quelque chose ; un enfant qui n'arrive pas à apprendre sa table de multiplications l'est, mais n'a aucune opinion sur celle-ci (sauf qu'il s'en passerait volontiers) ;

2- "*fanatique*" a une idée de violence ; mais si je demande toujours à un nouvel hôte comment il souhaite que son thé soit servi, cela ne dégénère jamais en pugilat, ni même en échange d'insultes ;

3- "*extrémiste*" suggère quelqu'un qui pousse une logique dans ses conclusions les plus lointaines ; personnellement, il me semble plus logique de mettre dans l'ordre sucre, lait, et enfin thé, pour assurer un meilleur mélange ; mais je ne suis pas extrémiste au point de traiter ceux qui préfèrent opérer autrement d'individus à l'esprit illogique (le goût a des raisons que la raison ne connaît point) ;

4- "*intégriste*" et "*zélote*" signifient le respect absolu, aveugle, entier (d'où le nom) d'une croyance, et non seulement d'une opinion.

5- Je serais *bigot*, sectaire, si je refusais de servir mes hôtes autrement que dans mon ordre préféré, ou alors en ne cachant pas ma réprobation.

**Personne ne peut être certain de l'étymologie**

J'aime assez, parce qu'elle est amusante, *bigot* comme une insulte anglaise contre les Normands (By God), à laquelle le français a répondu par "godon" (God dam')

Answer (score 1):

On peut également penser, pour ce qui est d'un terme proche du point de vue également de la sonorité, au [*cagot* "cher" au Sud-Ouest](http://ccrh.revues.org/2521), qui évoque une pratique philistine et dévote de la religion, fréquent notamment chez Nietzsche (ou plutôt dans sa traduction, en tout cas, car le terme ainsi traduit, *Duckmäuser*, si j'en crois une rapide recherche, évoque plutôt l'hypocrisie en allemand).

Comment: À [bigotisme](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/bigotisme) on retrouve, en plus de cagotisme, hypocrisie et tartuferie. L'[hypocrite](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/hypocrite) et le [tartufe](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/tartufe) sont aussi appropriés, à mon avis, et feraient de bons compléments à la réponse.

Answer (score 1):

Il me semble que *réactionnaire* recouvre en partie l'idée de *bigot* et *bigoted* en anglais, avec l'avantage de l'abréviation en *réac* qui peut servir à invectiver quelqu'un, tout comme *bigot*.

Ainsi on pourrait traduire les deux exemples suivants, tirés du *Longman Dictionary of Contemporary English* :

- a bigoted old man — *un vieux réac*
- She had always prided herself on her tolerance and open-mindedness - how dared he call her bigoted? — *Elle s'était toujours targuée d'être tolérante et ouverte d'esprit - Comment osait-il la traiter de réactionnaire.*